# can "took off" be used as "left"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> he's been tasked with surveying Quarray. so he **took off** a minute ago.

I'm wondering if "took off" can be used as simply "left".
and also, Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, took off means left in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context presented, *took off* can reasonably replaced with *left*. In other cases, the context will be important to determine meaning as they both have a few definitions.

> **take off** *verb*
>   *transitive verb*
>   1 : REMOVE
>
> > take your shoes off
>
> 2a : to take or allow as a discount : DEDUCT
>
> > took 10 percent off
>
> b : to spend (a period of time) away from a usual occupation or activity
>
> > took two weeks off
>
> c : RELEASE
>
> > take the brake off
>
> d : DISCONTINUE, WITHDRAW
>
> > took off the morning train
>
> 3 slang : ROB
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> 1a : to start off or away often suddenly : SET OUT, DEPART
>
> > took off for her trip
>
> b : to leave the surface : begin flight
>   c : to spring into wide use or popularity
>   d(1) : to branch off (as from a main stream or stem)
>   (2) : to take a point of origin
>   e : to begin a leap or spring
>   f : to embark on rapid activity, development, or growth
>   2 : to take away : DETRACT
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/took%20off</sup>

---

> **leave** *verb*
>   \ˈlēv  \
>   left\ ˈleft  \; leaving
>   *transitive verb*
>   1a(1) : BEQUEATH, DEVISE
>
> > left a fortune to his son
>
> (2) : to have remaining after one's death
>
> > leaves a widow and two children
>
> b : to cause to remain as a trace or aftereffect
>
> > oil leaves a stain
> >     the wound left an ugly scar
>
> 2a : to cause or allow to be or remain in a specified condition
>
> > leave the door open
> >     his manner left me cold
>
> b : to fail to include or take along
>
> > left the notes at home
> >     the movie leaves a lot out
>
> c : to have as a remainder
>
> > 4 from 7 leaves 3
>
> d : to permit to be or remain subject to another's action or control
>
> > just leave everything to me
>
> e : LET
>   f : to cause or allow to be or remain available
>
> > leave room for expansion
> >     left myself an out
>
> 3a : to go away from : DEPART
>
> > leave the room
>
> b : DESERT, ABANDON
>
> > left his wife
>
> c : to terminate association with : withdraw from
>
> > left school before graduation
>
> 4 : to put, deposit, or deliver before or in the process of departing
>
> > I left a package for you
> >     leave a message
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   : SET OUT, DEPART
>
> > left for the office at eight sharp
> >     leave alone
>
> : to refrain from bothering, disturbing, or using
>
> > Leave him alone while he's doing his homework.
>
> <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave</sup>

Whenever you can find a meaning in both of these, then you can replace them. The replacement is not always direct. For example, you could say:

> She **took** two weeks **off**.
>   She **left** for two weeks.

The difference in meaning is sometimes subtle and may not always be an issue.

Comment: Your formatting makes these definitions very hard to read. Please try to make them closer to what  you see on the site you took them from. Start with a much less liberal use of ">>" in your markdown.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer to make it more readable for yourself. I couldn't find a good way to do bullets inside a quote.